# Custom views in android

Tags: android, layout, view

I just started learning on how to make custom views .I created a drawable at the bottom of the screen and a small circle within it. The layout works perfectly fine but there is a small issue , the drawable in different resolution is cropped . Its works fine in S3 but in other devices the things are different. [image]

[image]

Here is my code :

```
 @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {


    int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);


    setMeasuredDimension(childWidthMeasureSpec,childHeightMeasureSpec);


}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Drawable outer_ring = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.outer_ring);

    System.out.println("Height now is : "+(canvas.getHeight()));

    Rect r1 = new Rect();
    r1.top = (canvas.getHeight()-outer_ring.getIntrinsicHeight());
    r1.bottom = canvas.getHeight();
    r1.left = (canvas.getWidth()-outer_ring.getIntrinsicWidth())/2;
    r1.right = canvas.getWidth()/2 +outer_ring.getIntrinsicWidth()/2;

    outer_ring.setBounds(r1);
    outer_ring.draw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);

    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, ((canvas.getHeight()-outer_ring.getIntrinsicHeight()/2)), 20, paint);
}
```

what should be the solution that this view appears same on all resolution

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <com.example.testing.CustomMenu
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you log the r1.bottom values on both devices? are they same with device's height?

Comment: Ya i did that . In S3 its little less then the device height : 1134 then the actual 1280. In other device which has a resolution of 480 x 854 its showing exact value

Comment: can you put your complete onDraw(), there is missing part

Comment: I have added the code please check now

Comment: the problem is with getIntrinsicHeight() method, it just returns the unmodified height of ring, e.g if its height is 200px then it will return 200 both on s3 and on other devices as well. use getWidth() instead

Comment: No help . showing this error when using getHeight() "The method getHeight() is undefined for the type Drawable"

Comment: I tried changing drawable to bitmapdrawable and get the height but then too its showing the same. moreover I check the value using getHeight and getIntrinsicHeight, they appears to be same. I know the difference but not able to figure it out

Comment: hımm do you have to draw it at bottom? center works too ?

Comment: ya i can do that but i was trying to make menu item similar to that in catch application. I already implemented their jar and got success but I thought of making one on my own .

Comment: hımm, if you dont have to; try to make the drawable also circle with gradient,

Comment: What happens if you don't override `onMeasure`?

Comment: I didn't tried that Neil but I will make the changes and let you know

Comment: @NeilTownsend I tried that but no change . Still the bitmap is cropped from bottom .

Comment: @NeilTownsend IF I am using Windows.Feature_No_title and this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
 The display will be correct can you justify this

Comment: Could you post the layout xml please? That might clarify something in my thinking. It's an interesting issue!

Comment: @NeilTownsend I have added the layout xml please check now.

Comment: I've put an answer below, did it help?

Comment: @NeilTownsend Ya i tried to implement your answer but the result was same... I got busy wd something so not able to do more R & D but I will give it another shot today... hope i am able to solve it... If i get the answer I will share it here...Its a strange behavior BTW

Comment: Fair point, I've done some more research and updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

It turns out the the size of the canvas provided to `onDraw` isn't guaranteed to be the same size as the actual viewed size of the `View`. It is merely guaranteed to be sufficiently large. In your case, it is too big!

According to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652400/how-can-i-get-the-canvas-size-of-a-custom-view-outside-of-the-ondraw-method), the key is to use the sizes returned in `onSizeChanged` as definitive for the current displayed size of the `View`. So you should retain the dimensions from `onSizeChanged`, and use them in `onDraw` to know the actual size you should draw to. *ie*,:

- `childWidthMeasureSpec` and `childHeightMeasureSpec` should become class variables which are set in `onSizeChanged`.
- In `onDraw`, use them instead of `canvas.getWidth()` and `canvas.getHeight()` respectively.

Whilst this behaviour seems a bit odd at first glance, it allows android to lower the number of canvas re-allocations it makes when sorting out sizes: If a `View` shrinks a bit (*eg.* with the appearance of a top bar) all it does it tell all concerned that the actual size is a bit smaller, rather than going through a canvas release and re-creation loop.

Probably less significant, in your java code, you request the dimensions of the `View` you are drawing. In the xml, you set those dimensions as `wrap_content`. This means that there is no explicit setting of the size of the `View`. A View like this should request the maximum size it can be, and the determine how large it wishes to be given that, and set that as its size. It's wiser to ensure that the dimesnions are fixed by setting the sizes of `CustomMenu` to `match_patent`, so that they are fixed.

However, in the absence of that, the parent `View` has given you some bounds. It appears that these bounds may, or may not, take account of the top bar, which is fair enough.

Comment: Thanks for your time and solution. That was really helpful and solved my problem. All the effort you put in was fruitful finally.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.getHeight()` instead of `canvas.getHeight()` and `this.getWidth()` instead of `canvas.getWidth()`.

(`this` relates to the `View`)

Comment: I will try your selotion too but see Neils comment and solution. That solved my problem