# Android Canvas Gradient

Tags: android, canvas, gradient

[image: Example]

I try to draw this on Android canvas, and I have questions...

1. Why all shaders results have only white and black? There are no colors...
2. How to set color for more than two points (x,y)?
3. Where can I find examples that will show simple combinations of use?

Code:

```
Shader1 = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0,BarHeight,0xff696969 ,0xffffffff,   Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Shader2 = new LinearGradient(BarHeight/2, BarHeight/2, 0,34,0xf0696969 ,0xfff34f5f, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
ComposeShader mShader = new ComposeShader(Shader2, Shader1,  PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
GraundPaint.setShader(mShader);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectf, 0, 0, GraundPaint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set **more than 2 points** by using [this constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html#LinearGradient(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20int[],%20float[],%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode)) of LinearGradient, which takes an array of colors and the corresponding array of positions (between 0 and 1).

For a **simple example** using LinearGradient, you may look [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/09/lineargradient-example.html).

Comment: Thank You! I'm a newBie so it was rather stupid question(

Comment: Glad if I could help, I don't think there is such a thing as a stupid question :)

Comment: I have more questions((

Can i get width and height of the screen but not in  OnDraw()? Im trying to create all Shaders (Odjects) before OnDraw(), but it have some dependence from width and height of the screen ..

Comment: Just search around here on Stack Overflow, there are plenty of Android questions. This one might help with getting the width and height: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6652621/3160869 
Also, if you cannot find what you're looking for, you can post a new (separate) question. Stack Overflow is all about making it easy for other people to find your questions later.